# Is it possible to run pre-Lion OS X in an IPv6-only environment without static configuration?

Tags: networking, mac-osx, ipv6, isc-dhcp

Is it possible to run pre-Lion OS X in an IPv6-only environment without static configuration?  From what I've been able to figure out, OS X 10.6.x will acquire an address via SLAAC, but it doesn't appear to support either DHCPv6 or the RDNSS/DNSSL options in router advertisements, which means that for name lookup to work one has to manually configured a DNS server.

Are there any alternatives?  Third-party solutions that integrate well with the native network configuration tools?  I'm building the ISC DHCP client (4.2.3) right now, which does support DHCPv6, but the configuration is orthagonal to the OS X network preference pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no. You can run 10.6.8 in ipv6 only, but it requires manual configuration of dns. There is no support for DHCPv6 and as far as I can tell there is no third-party products as of January 2012.

Karyn

Answer (score 1):

Yes, OSX < 10.7 does not support working in ipv6 mode only. But for your case, this discussion thread might come useful

[Does 10.6.8 support DHCPv6?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3147259?start=0&tstart=0)